# How to unpack/destructure an array in D?

Tags: arrays, d, destructuring

How to unpack/destructure an array in D?

I have an array (`[3,4,5]`) of three elements and want to assign it to three variables (`a`, `b`, `c`) with one assignment.

How would I do this in D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [tie](https://github.com/valmat/vest#tie) from my dub package [vest](https://code.dlang.org/packages/vest):

```
import vest.utils: tie;
int a,b,c;
tie(a,b,c) = [1, 2, 2];
```

tie supports arrays, ranges, tuples

Answer (score 1):

The module `letassign.d` at https://bitbucket.org/infognition/dstuff/src allows the following code:

```
int x, y, z;
let (x,y,z) = [1,2,3];
```

This should be in the standard D library, by the way!

Comment: Wowa, that is a cool library, cleaver implementation.  I love what you can do with D with just libraries!